# Final state radiation and Bremsstrahlung

Tags: particle-physics, electromagnetic-radiation, experimental-physics

Is the final state radiation, whereby a photon is emitted, of a particle caused by Bremsstrahlung, or are the two different effects?

Comment: Could you rephrase? This is hard to understand.

Comment: What is "final state radiation" ?

Comment: For example, the Drell-Yan process whereby two leptons are produced in the final state, one of these leptons radiate a photon

Comment: To get the attention of a commenter  xxx  on your question you have to put the @xxx so he/she is alerted there is a reply

Comment: Thank you very much Anna! I will keep it in mind for next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, final state radiation is a type of bremsstrahlung.

Answer (score -1):

Your example of "final state radiation" in the comments

[image: drell yan]

> [Drell–Yan process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drell%E2%80%93Yan_process): a quark from one hadron and an antiquark from another hadron annihilate to create a pair of leptons through the exchange of a virtual photon.

In the DY there is no electromagnetic radiation, DY is  the annihilation of a quark antiquark pair  to two leptons. The two leptons may after exiting the interaction have another electromagnetic interaction that will lead to photons, including [bremsstrahlung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung).

There is no process that is called "final state radiation" AFAIK.

Comment: Hi Anna, thank you very much for your answer, I wasn't claiming the final state radiation to be a process on its own, but I was more interested what would cause it, but as I suspected, there is no other "process" to explain it except with Bremsstrahlung.